# ивент по финишу работы потоков

Tags: c#, многопоточность, события

У меня есть некая задача которая занимает несколько минут времени.

Что бы сделать работу быстрее хочу создать ивент по окончанию работы всех потоков, что б по ивенту уже был вызов нужного мне метода.

---

Немного детальнее:

У меня есть некий класс, в котором хранится большой список хостов. Даный клас имеет в себе метод для пинга хостов -- проверка и их доступности(и сохранение результатов внутри экземпляра). Я решил делать пинги даного списка хостов многопоточно. Например в 8 потоков, которые создаются циклом.

Мне нужно что бы, по окончанию работы, экзепляр даного класа кинул ивент в форму что все окончилось и нужно обновить список в форме.

Упрощенный код формы:

```
private HostList _hostList;

private void OnButtonClick()
{
    await hostList.ChekAccess();
    UpdateDataGridView();
}

//Need to call on ChekAccess() finish
private void  UpdateDataGridView()
{ /**/ }
```

Упрощенный код HostList

```
    async public void ChekAccess(int threadsCounter = 8)
    {
                    int range = Hosts.Count / threadsCounter;
                    int lastRange = Hosts.Count % threadsCounter;

                    Task[] tasks = new Task[threadsCounter];

                    for (int i = 0; i < threadsCounter - 1; i++)
                {
                    tasks[i] = CheckActuality(i * range, range);
                }

                tasks[threadsCounter - 1] = CheckActuality((threadsCounter - 1) * range, lastRange );

                    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

async private void CheckActuality(int start, int length)
{
/**/
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно делать вовсе не так, а через Task и async/await.

```
async Task Goal1() { ... }
async Task Goal2() { ... }

// ...
async Task Process()
{
    await Task.WhenAll(Goal1(), Goal2());
    // вызывайте здесь нужный метод, оба задания завершились
```

---

Это модельный код; если нам нужно по окончанию его работы вызвать UI-функцию, нужно снова-таки воспользоваться await из UI-кода:

```
async void OnClick()
{
    button.Enabled = false;
    var result = await model.Process();
    textfield.Text = result;
    button.Enabled = true;
}
```

---

Для случая кода в вопросе подойдёт такое:

```
private HostList _hostList;

async void OnButtonClick()
{
    await hostList.CheckAccess();
    UpdateDataGridView();
}

// ...

async public void CheckAccess()
{
    Task[] tasks = new Task[Hosts.Count];

    for (int i = 0; i < Hosts.Count - 1; i++)
        tasks[i] = CheckActuality(i * range, range);

    tasks[Hosts.Count - 1] = CheckActuality((Hosts.Count - 1) * range, lastRange);

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Функция `CheckActuality` тоже должна быть `async`-функцией, и в ней не должно быть длительных синхронных вызовов.

---

Вообще, на текущий момент правильным является использование async/await [all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down), т. к. основная причина ожидания — не процессор, а обмен информацией с внешним миром (файлы, базы данных, сеть). Те куски, которые реально требуют отдельный поток (то есть, те, у которых узкое место — процессор), нужно обернуть в `Task.Run` и тоже общаться с ними через async/await.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35783/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-----).